# I want to add new Userwith angular js and asp mvc

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc

i want to add a new user when i click in the button dosen't work Is there a problem with the code

```
  public string Insert_Users(AspNetUser aspNetUser)
    {
        if (aspNetUser != null)
        {

            {
                db.AspNetUsers.Add(aspNetUser);
                db.SaveChanges();
                return "User Added Successfully";
            }
        }
        else
        {
            return "User Not Inserted! Try Again";
        }
    }
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Change Your Code like This:

```
 public string Insert_Users(AspNetUserModel aspNetUser)
        {
            if (aspNetUser != null)
            {
                AspNetUser model = new AspNetUser();
                model.Email = aspNetUser.Email;
                model.PhoneNumber = aspNetUser.PhoneNumber;
                model.UserName = aspNetUser.UserName;
                {
                    db.AspNetUsers.Add(model);
                    db.SaveChanges();
                    return "User Added Successfully";
                }
            }
            else
            {
                return "User Not Inserted! Try Again";
            }
        }
```

**Add Model**

```
 public class AspNetUserModel
    {
        public string Email {get;set;}    //SET Your DataType
        public string UserName {get;set;} //SET Your DataType 
        public int PhoneNumber {get;set;} //SET Your DataType 
    }
```